# Dimension Leap with A Held Rope

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, teleportation, objects

My Bard is holding one end of a 100' rope in his hand. The other end of the rope is in a row-boat, either tied to the boat or held by another character in the boat.

The Bard casts Dimension Leap to teleport 90' away.

What happens to the rope? We are trying to create a tether to attach a row boat to a ship, to be able to pull the row boat to the ship.

Comment: If the question was "How do i move one end of a rope 90' away", then you might more useful suggestions. Mundane solutions like tying it to an arrow or magical solutions such as [Animate Rope](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/animateRope.htm). Book of Exalted Deeds has rules for a lasso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on a DM ruling on whether the rope is part of the boat.

The spell describes that interaction with other objects by stating:

> You can bring along any objects you are touching as the spell is cast, so long as their weight doesn't exceed your maximum load. You cannot bring along other creatures.

If the rope isn't part of the boat, then you can take it with you, but the rope won't be attached to the boat anymore. Since you don't "move" through space to your destination but instead instantly appear in the new position. The rope would retain whatever knots where used to tie it to the boat.

If the rope is part of the boat, then only you will teleport to the destination.

Theoretically if the rope was stretched it out before the Dimension Leap, then you could take it with you, letting one end land with you on the ship and the other end land by the boat. It still wouldn't be tied to the boat though.